# How to return custom Key value pair from spring-cloud-config-server?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am using spring-cloud-config-server , I do not want Git backend or file system based backend . I want custom Key value pair to be returned.

Comment: where would your properties lie then?

Comment: I am going to put the properties in Azure KeyVault

Comment: I do not think the  config server supports this , but this should be a good addition , can u make an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found solution of this . 

1) on the application.properties set spring.profiles.active=native

2) Create CustomEnvironmentRepository -- Refer code on #A

3) Register CustomEnvironmentRepository Bean  -- Refer code on #B

#A - 



    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository;
    import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
    public class CustomEnvironmentRepository implements 
    EnvironmentRepository, Ordered
    {
        @Override
        public Environment findOne(String application, String profile, String label)
        {
            Environment environment = new Environment(application, profile);

            final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("mycustomPropertyKey", "myValue");
            environment.add(new PropertySource("mapPropertySource", properties));
            return environment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
        }
    }

#B 

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    @EnableConfigServer
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MyCloudConfigApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MyCloudConfigApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public  EnvironmentRepository environmentRepository() {
            return new CustomEnvironmentRepository();
        }
    }

Test by invoking - http://localhost:9092/my-cloud-config.properties

You will see
mycustomPropertyKey: myValue

My Original Goal is to set some properties from Azure Key Vault , I guess integrating AzureKey Vault in CustomEnvironmentRepository , I should be able to achieve this 

Application Properties File will look like

    server.port=<YOUR_PORT>
    spring.profiles.active=native
    azure.keyvault.uri=<YOUR_AZURE_URI_CAN_BE_FOUND_IN_AZURE_PORTAL>
    azure.keyvault.client-id=<YOUR_AZURE_CLIENT_ID_CAN_BE_FOUND_IN_AZURE_PORTAL>
    azure.keyvault.client-key=<YOUR_AZURE_CLIENT_KEY_CAN_BE_FOUND_IN_AZURE_PORTAL>

IN POM Use these Dependencies 

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am able to successfully leverage above solution to read properties from Azure Key vault on cloud config server

Comment: can you please post your solution with azure key vault for config server ?

Comment: Use code snippet above . I have added properties file and Maven POM file  configuration.